# Downvoting: Is there a difference between ones right and arbitrary punishment?

Tags: discussion

I understand the users right to downvote whatever the reason but I have experienced something recently that has made me wonder whether there is a boundary between right and abuse. Basically I feel hard done by because of this (a.k.a poor me).

I fear as though I may have been downvoted by another answerer recently because I commented on his answer asking for clarification and references.

The user in question then added my information to his answer and took credit for it.

As I said I understand a persons right to downvote but is there a boundary to this right?

Answer (score 3):

You don't even know *that* the other answerer downvoted you, let alone why whoever did downvote you choose to do so.

You are merely guessing on both counts.

---

To answer your literal question of what boundries are there when voting, you are not allowed to vote on posts of other accounts of yours, or to vote in such a way that a moderator is confident that you are voting on a large portion of a user's posts entirely because that user posted them, rather than because of the content of those posts; in practice this means that if you vote on a lot of one person's posts in a short period of time, it's generally considered voting fraud.

Comment: He did say he downvoted and it happened 2 secs after comment, it would have to very high coincidence

Comment: @Sammaye Sure, but it's still a guess.  I've seen people say they downvoted when I know they didn't, or given one reason for downvoting when that wasn't their true (or at least only) reason for doing so.

Comment: I suppose though whenever he has said -1 he has always downvoted, but yeah, fair enough

Comment: @Sammaye And you would suppose incorrectly.  As I've said, you cannot assume that someone has downvoted you just because they say so in comments.

Comment: -1 The downvote arrow is the one above the number, isn't it?

Comment: @JonK If you're looking at it in a mirror above your monitor, yes, yes it is.

Comment: @Servy Oh. I think that might explain my vote ratio. Hmmm